# Run handlers regardless of task failure?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role, ansible-handlers

I have [an Ansible role](https://github.com/naftulikay/ansible-role-degoss/) which has [the following tasks](https://github.com/naftulikay/ansible-role-degoss/blob/3a22006f8f069142b6696aea4a60d193412ae816/tasks/main.yml):

```
---
 # optionally find the latest version of goss using the GitHub "API"
 - name: detect latest version
   shell: |
    curl -sIS https://github.com/aelsabbahy/goss/releases/latest | \
      tr -d '\r' | \
      grep -oP '(?<=Location:\s).*' | \
      grep -oP '(?<=v)\d+\.\d+\.\d+'
   register: detected_latest
   when: version == "latest"

 - name: set detected version
   set_fact:
     real_version: "{{ detected_latest.stdout.strip() }}"
   when: version == "latest"

 - name: set specified verison
   set_fact:
     real_version: "{{ version }}"
   when: version != "latest"

 # set play facts
 - name: set facts
   set_fact:
     download_url: "https://github.com/aelsabbahy/goss/releases/download/v{{ real_version }}/goss-linux-amd64"

 # create goss directories
 - name: create goss directories
   file: path={{ item }} state=directory
   with_items:
     - /tmp/degoss
     - /tmp/degoss/bin
     - /tmp/degoss/tests
   notify: clean

 # download goss
 - name: install
   get_url:
     url: "{{ download_url }}"
     dest: /tmp/degoss/bin/goss
     mode: 0755

 # deploy test cases
 - name: deploy tests
   copy: src={{ item }} dest=/tmp/degoss/tests/
   with_items: "{{ tests }}"

 # run the tests
 - name: run tests
   goss: executable=/tmp/degoss/bin/goss path="{{ item }}" format="{{ format }}"
   with_fileglob: /tmp/degoss/tests/*.yml
```

Namely, when `create goss directories` is run, it triggers [the `clean` handler](https://github.com/naftulikay/ansible-role-degoss/blob/3a22006f8f069142b6696aea4a60d193412ae816/handlers/main.yml):

```
---
# handlers file for degoss
 - name: clean
   file: path=/tmp/degoss state=absent
```

Due to the nature of my module, I want the `clean` handler to *always* run, even if other tasks in the role have failed. From my cursory testing, if `run tests` fails, the handler is never called and the temporary files are left on the target machine.

Is there a way from within my role to force Ansible to run this handler regardless of what happened in the tasks?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the [Handlers and Failure](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html#handlers-and-failure) chapter:

> You can change this behavior with the `--force-handlers` command-line option, or by including `force_handlers: True` in a play, or `force_handlers = True` in `ansible.cfg`. When handlers are forced, they will run when notified even if a task fails on that host. (Note that certain errors could still prevent the handler from running, such as a host becoming unreachable.)

Comment: This would have been more useful if you included an example...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to run force_handlers on the playbook. Keep in mind that if you have a task that creates something but can return error even after the creation worked, the notify on the task will not run and will not activate the handler.

```
---
  - name: handler test
    hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: false
    force_handlers: true
    tasks:

      - name: Return true
        shell: /bin/true
        notify: test_debug

      - name: test broken task
        shell: /bin/false
        notify: test_debug_2

      - name: this one should not run
        debug:
          msg: blabla
        tags:
          - always # This tag will not work

    handlers:
      - name: test_debug
        debug:
          msg: testing error handling

      - name: test_debug_2
        debug:
          msg: testing error handling 2 this one will not run
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    ---
    # tasks file for block
    - name: command 0
      shell: uname -i

    - block:
      - name: command1
        shell: ls /tmp/
      - name: command2
        shell: ls /tmp/momo

  rescue:
  - name: retour arriere ya eu une erreur
    shell: ls -ls
```

Comment: No explanation, nothing to do with handlers and broken YAML indentation...

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).